# Running redux example without nodejs server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, redux

Im newbie with node, redux, webpack and react. I found this examples:

http://rackt.org/redux/docs/introduction/Examples.html

I successfully run the Universal example. But my client doesn't want to run node.js server on production.. Is there anyway I could generate bundle.js at build time and upload everything to their server?

All examples i found use webpack-dev-server (node express server), is it possible to create bundle file and simply serve it as a simple static file?

Comment: Yes. You're describing a typical deployment scenario. But you do understand that you need a webserver application (node, IIS, Apache, etc.) to serve the files don't you?

Comment: Yes, JBoss in production but i have Apache locally.. But from this axamples, how to convince to export bundle.js static file? I'm playing around but without any success..

Comment: Do you have a webpack.config.js? Are you building your bundle.js using webpack?

Comment: Here is the redux example: https://github.com/rackt/redux/blob/master/examples/todomvc/webpack.config.js . I tryied to play around, but not sucesfully..

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue. How did you resolve? I got Nginx running and I'm expecting a single bundle js that I can upload and run the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm facing the same issue. I wanna migrate a jsp views based Spring MVC app into a Redux/React client with the Spring as a data API/Backend for the client webapp, but with server side rendering benefits (Universal javascript).

For angular apps (only client side js), it's easy to serve a bundle for the browser, and then communicate with the backend via ajax, but with server side rendering everything gets more complicated.

The 2 questions I ask myself is: It does really worth all the extra complexity and work on architecture setting and maintaining? Will my innovation turn my project into daily headaches, caused by new development features and possible issues/bugs on production?

If your client is not going to appreciate, or really get much value (from a non-tech point of view), of your server side rendering architecture, maybe is not the best idea to give an extra frame of complexity to your project.

Best luck!

Answer (score 1):

It is not as simple as you envision, because the server generated views can be dynamic. So you will need some mechanism to run javascript in the server.

However as [this blog post](http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/02/16/isomorphic-react-webapps-on-the-jvm/) has elaborated in detail, you can The Nashorn JavaScript Engine to render react components on the server. That way your javascript engine is embedded in JVM and you will not have to run a separate node process.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to run a universal application — one that prerenders on the server and also works on the client (like the universal example in the repo) — then no, you must run Node.js in order to do server rendering. You can easily export a single bundle to run the app on the *client* side, but to run it on the *server* side you'll need a server technology that can actually run it, like Node.

Comment: Ok, but how then to do it for todomvc example. Webpack config is here, but it does not produce bundle.js on the file system..: https://github.com/rackt/redux/blob/master/examples/todomvc/webpack.config.js

Answer (score 0):

You can try [redux-auto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-auto)

> redux-auto: Redux made easy (with a plug and play approach).
>   Removing the boilerplate code in setting up a store & actions

The [**example**](https://github.com/codemeasandwich/redux-auto/tree/master/example) has evenything setup + hot-reloading.

You just need to run `npm install` then `npm start`

Answer (score 0):

I have created a fidlle .
https://jsfiddle.net/parthmakadiya12/z8dLrhqv/2/
It's not advisable to use it for real world implementation.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/3.6.0/redux.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        Counter:
        <span id="counter"></span>
    </div>
    <button id="inc">Increment</button>
    <button id="dec">Decrement</button>
</body>
<script>
    function reducer(state, action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'INC':
                return {...state, counter: action.payload
                };
            case 'DEC':
                return {...state, counter: state.counter - 1
                };
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
    const initialState = {
        counter: 0
    }
    const store = Redux.createStore(reducer, initialState);

    function upDateData() {
        document.getElementById('counter').innerText = store.getState().counter;
    }
    store.subscribe(upDateData)
    document.getElementById('inc').onclick = () => {
        store.dispatch({
            type: 'INC',
            payload: store.getState().counter + 1
        });

    };
    document.getElementById('dec').onclick = () => {
        store.dispatch({
            type: 'DEC'
        })
        payload: store.getState().counter + 1
    };
</script>

</html>
```